# Android Studio - Custom ListView Crashing App

Tags: android

I have a custom ListView which is meant to take JSON data and display it to the user, but whenever I call it, it ends up crashing

Main Class

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

//Change Activity
//Log Out
public void OpenBeginningActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Beginning.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//Take Picture
public void TakePicture(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
}

//JSON Variables
final String TAG = Main.class.getSimpleName();
final String JSONUrl = "http://iameuropeapp.pythonanywhere.com/getcountries";
private ArrayList<Country> CountryList;

//Variables
private ProgressDialog ProgressDialog;
private String UserEmail;
private FirebaseAuth FirebaseInstance;
private FirebaseAuth FirebaseAuthentication;
private FirebaseUser LoggedInUser;
private TextView UserEmailText;
private ListView CountryListView;
private ListAdapter Adapter;

public void ParseJSON(View view){

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Change Bar Title
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dashboard");

    //Get Components
    UserEmailText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.UserEmail);
    FirebaseInstance = FirebaseAuthentication.getInstance();
    LoggedInUser = FirebaseInstance.getCurrentUser();

    //Set Username
    UserEmailText.setText(LoggedInUser.getEmail());

    //ListView
    CountryList = new ArrayList<>();
    CountryListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CountryList);

    //Countries
    new GetCountries().execute();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Take Photo
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.MenuItem1){
        TakePicture();
    }

    //Sign Out
    else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.MenuItem2){
        FirebaseAuthentication.getInstance().signOut();
        OpenBeginningActivity();
        ProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing out...");
        ProgressDialog.show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class GetCountries extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        ProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
        ProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        ProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HttpHandler Handler = new HttpHandler();
        String JSONString = Handler.makeServiceCall(JSONUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response:" + JSONString);

        if(JSONString != null){
            try {
                JSONObject CountriesJSONObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);
                JSONArray Countries = CountriesJSONObject.getJSONArray("countries");

                for (int i = 0; i < Countries.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Country = Countries.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("country");
                    String CountryID = Country.getString("id");
                    String CountryName = Country.getString("name");
                    String CountryImage = Country.getString("image");
                    CountryList.add(new Country(CountryID, CountryName, CountryImage));
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e){
                Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
                ProgressDialog.setMessage("Error loading Data!");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void Result)
    {
        ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        ListAdapter CustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Main.this,0,CountryList);
        CountryListView.setAdapter(CustomAdapter);

    }

}

}
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country>{

public ArrayList<Country> ArrayListCountries;

public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context,int resource, ArrayList<Country> Countries) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_main_list, Countries);
}

@Override
public View getView(int Position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup){
    //Init
    LayoutInflater Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View CustomView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_list, viewgroup, false);

    //Get Components
    Country country = ArrayListCountries.get(Position);
    TextView CountryText = (TextView) CustomView.findViewById(R.id.CountryNameText);
    ImageView CountryImage = (ImageView) CustomView.findViewById(R.id.CountryImage);

    //Set Values
    CountryText.setText(country.name);

    //End
    return CustomView;
}
}
```

Country Class

```
public class Country {
public String id, name, image;

public Country (String id, String name, String image) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

This is the only issue currently holding me back from continuing as the features that come after this require the user to access the listview. I've been struggling all day to actually make this work.

Comment: Error Log, please.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: edit your question with the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initialising the list instance in adapter so do it like

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country>{

    public ArrayList<Country> ArrayListCountries;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context,int resource, ArrayList<Country> Countries) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_main_list, Countries);
        ArrayListCountries = Countries;
       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
//...
}
```

OR

As you are passing your list to array adapter using `super` call so you can directly fetch item using [getItem(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem(int))

```
Country country = getItem(Position);
```

Note: it is ideal to use naming convention with references stats with small case as `arrayListCountries` and `countries`

Comment: It works! But i'm having a bit of an issue, it is not showing any text, it is showing the default image and it is scrollable through

Comment: there could be two reasons , 1) either you have no data so check the value of `country.name` or there is a layout issue mean something wrong with `R.layout.activity_main_list ` look into these and I am glad that I could help, happy coding

Comment: to load the image , you can use Picasso or glide